# Read xml base64 content in vb

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I try to decode the xml content from base64 to string
this my code
the inr1 is xmlReader

```
Dim inv As String = inr1.ReadElementContentAsString()
```

'the inv have value ok [ aGVsbG8= ] whic is hello

```
Dim binv() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inv)
```

'the binv have value ok

```
Dim n3 As String = inr1.ReadElementContentAsBase64(binv, 0, binv.Length).ToString
```

but the n3 is Nothing :( ?